# Unity3D / Django rest api

Tags: python, django, unity-game-engine, django-rest-framework

I am developing a graphic interface with unity and want it to interact with a Django REST API. I don't seem to have any documentation on this issue. Is this possible ? Do you have any documentation that could help ?

Comment: What do you really need? You have C# on Unity3D side. You can use the same methods you would use on C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any C# function to communicate to a web server. You might only have restrictions depending on the platform, for example, android will bock web access if you don't explicitly require it in the manifest.

Unity also provides helper for web communication. Have a look at the [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) class to send data, or the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class to retrieve data.

This [page of the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) provides a complete example

**Example, how to collect data:**

```
public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
IEnumerator Start()
{
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        yield return www;
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

**Example, how to send data**

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Upload());
}

IEnumerator Upload() {
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection("field1=foo&field2=bar") );
    formData.Add( new MultipartFormFileSection("my file data", "myfile.txt") );

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://www.my-server.com/myform", formData);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```